# Angular & rxjs catch error when find returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am trying to figure out how to catch an error when the variable `selectionId` that I define from my route is either null, or an invalid value. Currently, if my `category` variable is undefined, it is caught by the rxjs function catchError, and throws to my error subscription block appropriately.

But when `selectionId` is undefined, it still goes into the success block, where the successful result is undefined.

```
loadSelection() {
    // define the menu category chosen (e.g. 'pizza')
    const category = this.route.snapshot.url[0].path;
    // define which item in the menu was selected (e.g. 1)
    const selectionId = this.route.snapshot.url[1].path;

    // in the menu state at the given category, find the menu item with the matching selectionId
    this.store.select('menu')
    .pipe(map(menuState => menuState.menu.groupedMenu[category]
    .find(selection => selection._id === selectionId)),
    catchError(err => throwError('given category does not exist'))
    ).subscribe(
    (selection: Selection) => { // success case
        this.selection = selection;
    },
    (err) => { // error case
        console.log('weow', err);
    });
}
```

What is the best way to handle errors when my `.find` returns undefined?

I could just put an if statement checking for undefined in my success block, but I don't feel like this is clean code. But maybe I'm wrong.

Thank you for any help

Comment: This is kind of preference / opinion but I take the stance that an error means something went wrong that you didn’t intend or anticipate. If your stream can return undefined and you’re aware of it, then you’re just handling a state of your stream. A lot of people won’t agree and think an error can be something anticipated or expected and it’s cleaner to handle it as an error. It’s really up to you though.

Comment: will there be a default selectionId needed?

Comment: no @FanCheung , not needed

Comment: @bryan60 you make a good point. It's weird to have two error handling cases here, to me though

Answer (score 0):

I realize that you are specifically asking how to handle the error in the rx stream,
but since you have both `category` and `selectionId` before you even do the `select`, 
why not just check and handle the error condition before the `select`?

Comment: yeah that's how I ended up doing it, was just hoping there might be a better way so that I don't have to handle errors in locations